# Creating a link to logout for JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

when a user logins to my application, he submits a form to be processed through the Servlet. The servlet creates a session for the user. How would I create a link so the user can logout? I cannot seem to directly link to a Servlet. How would I delete the session and link back to the homepage?

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null)
session.invalidate();
request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Answer (score 3):

Make a link `<a href="/logout.jspx">Logout</a>` where there will be a logout `Servlet` map to this url and you must invalidate the session this will remove session from server and redirect to homepage and server will create a new session for that.

Comment: how to put customised log out link in all pages right side when i was  successfully login please provide the jsp code to me

Comment: `<a href="/logout.jspx">Logout</a>` is a valid html, which you can put in all your jsps.

Comment: separate the logout code from all jsps and include the page in all jsps  using <%@ include file="/header.jsp" %>

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to write a method like logout.do

```
@RequestMapping("/logout.do")
 public ModelAndView logout(HttpSession session){
      session.invalidate();
      return new ModelAndView("/logout.jsp");//if you have two differenet web pages for login and logout else you can redirect to login.jsp
 }
```

and from your headerFile.jsp link it to

```
<a href="/logout.do">Logout</a>
```

Comment: and also provide the logout link on right side of the web page

Comment: you can put this link in your jsp where logout text displays <a href="/logout.do">Logout</a>