# Creating a logout link using jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Creating a link to logout for JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966762/creating-a-link-to-logout-for-jsp)

when a user logins to my application, after login the application i need a logout link to all my pages .so provide the  jsp code

```
  HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
   if(session != null)
            session.invalidate();
   request.getRequestDispatcher("/index.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Comment: plese have a look at this link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13966762/creating-a-link-to-logout-for-jsp/13967079#13967079

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate JSP for log out and import it in all JSP  at  position where you want to create logout link.

```
<jsp:include page="logOut.jsp" />
```